Closing a macro with other possible macros
I have an interface to build songs. It works (simplified for this case) like this:
\begin{canto}{<name>}
  \estrofa
  contenido de la estrofa\f

  \estrofa
  contenido de la estrofa\f

  \estribillo
  contenido del estribillo\f

  \estrofa
  contenido de la estrofa\f
\end{canto}

In this case, \f ends the argument absorption of both \estribillo and \estrofa, meaning that, simplifying, they are defined by \def\estrofa #1\f{...}. But my idea is to avoid having \f be explicit, so that every time \estrofa or \estribillo (or \end{canto}) is used, they automatically insert a \f before, so that the syntax becomes:
\begin{canto}{<name>}
  \estrofa
  contenido de la estrofa

  \estrofa
  contenido de la estrofa

  \estribillo
  contenido del estribillo

  \estrofa
  contenido de la estrofa
\end{canto}

I think the solution would be to use an auxiliary definition with \protect, but I can't figure out how to implement it. Any idea how I can do it? (I know with LuaLaTeX I could use string.gsub, but I'd prefer not to use that.)

Update 1: At the beginning of the song definition I use obeylines to deal with line breaks. I also have the catcode for # changed so that \estrofa# is listed and \estrofa is not. The reason I need to absorb the input is because I number and format them:
\begin{canto}{The name}
    \estrofa#
    primera linea
    segunda linea
    tercera linea\f

    \estribillo 
    text, text
    more text\f

    \estrofa#
    bla bla bla
    ble blu bli\f
\end{canto}

returns something like what you see in the following figure:

Here the definition of \estrofa#
{\catcode`\#=11
\catcode`\?=6
\long\gdef\estrofa# ?1 \f{
    \bool_set_true:N\l_canto_canto_estrofa_bool
    \int_gincr:N\l_canto_canto_estrofa_numero_int
    \tl_set:Nn\l_canto_estrofa_bruto_tl{?1}
    %\canto_parser_tonicas:N\l_canto_estrofa_bruto_tl

    \dim_set:Nn\g_canto_canto_estrofa_cuerpo_width_dim{\linewidth}
    \dim_sub:Nn
        \g_canto_canto_estrofa_cuerpo_width_dim
        {\dim_eval:n{\g_canto_canto_estrofa_numero_width_dim + \g_canto_canto_estrofa_numero_indent_skip}}
    
    \hbox_set_to_wd:Nnn \l_canto_canto_estrofa_numero_box { \g_canto_canto_estrofa_numero_width_dim }
        {\int_use:N \l_canto_canto_estrofa_numero_int .}

    \vbox_set_top:Nn \l_canto_canto_estrofa_cuerpo_box
        {\hsize\g_canto_canto_estrofa_cuerpo_width_dim\raggedright
        \l_canto_estrofa_bruto_tl
        }
    
    \skip_vertical:N\g_canto_canto_estrofa_arriba_skip
    \skip_horizontal:N\g_canto_canto_estrofa_numero_indent_skip
    \box_use:N\l_canto_canto_estrofa_numero_box
    \box_use:N\l_canto_canto_estrofa_cuerpo_box
    \skip_vertical:N\g_canto_canto_estrofa_abajo_skip
    }
}

and the definition of \estribillo:
\long\def\estribillo#1\f{
    \bool_set_true:N\l_canto_canto_estribillo_bool
    \tl_set:Nn\l_canto_estribillo_bruto_tl{#1}
    \canto_parser_tonicas:N\l_canto_estribillo_bruto_tl

    \dim_set:Nn\g_canto_canto_estribillo_cuerpo_width_dim{\linewidth}
    \dim_sub:Nn
        \g_canto_canto_estribillo_cuerpo_width_dim
        {\g_canto_canto_estribillo_cuerpo_indent_skip}

    \vbox_set_top:Nn
        \l_canto_canto_estribillo_cuerpo_box
        {\hsize\g_canto_canto_estribillo_cuerpo_width_dim\raggedright\slshape
        \l_canto_estribillo_bruto_tl}

    \skip_vertical:N\g_canto_canto_estribillo_arriba_skip
    \fbox{\skip_horizontal:N\g_canto_canto_estribillo_cuerpo_indent_skip}
    \fbox{\box_use:N\l_canto_canto_estribillo_cuerpo_box}
    \skip_vertical:N\g_canto_canto_estribillo_abajo_skip
}

It's old code too. I didn't know much about what it was doing. I have also learned a lot in all this time. I picked up the project last week and thought I could make \verse and \chorus make changes directly on the paragraph, without having to absorb. But I would like to know how to solve it the other way, just to learn something new. Thanks!

Update 2:
A functional example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}

\let\f\relax

\long\def\estrofa #1\f {\vbox{ #1 }} %<- vbox to avoid the break between pages (each line is a paragraph ->\obeylines).
\long\def\estribillo #1\f {\vbox{ #1 }} %<- vbot to avoid the break between pages.

\newenvironment{canto}{\bgroup\obeylines}{\egroup}

\begin{document}

%Current interface


\begin{canto}
    \estrofa
    linea 1
    linea 2
    linea 3\f
    
    \estrofa
    linea 1
    linea 2
    linea 3\f
    
    \estribillo
    linea 1
    linea 2
    linea 3\f
\end{canto}


%desired interface
\begin{comment}

\begin{canto}
    \estrofa
    linea 1
    linea 2
    linea 3
    
    \estrofa
    linea 1
    linea 2
    linea 3
    
    \estribillo
    linea 1
    linea 2
    linea 3
\end{canto}

\end{comment}
\end{document}


What exactly do you need the contents for? Do you actually have to absorb them as an argument or do you just put some stuff like \par and perhaps some other contents? Or do you really need to grab them for further processing? It would be nice if you could post your current definitions of \estrofa and \estribillo.

Hi, @Skillmon . Thanks for your reply. I attached some more information to the post. Regards!

don't provide disconnected fragments that can not be run and are very hard to guess what they are intended to do, just provide a small but complete test document that shows the problem and allows answers to be tested. It is rather unusual to need this at all eg standard latex list \item never scans over the item text.

why the catcode change for # ?? This makes it more complicated to code and will confuse users and syntax highligters why not use * for the exceptional cases like most other latex commands, rather than define a breaking latex syntax using # ?

Hi, @DavidCarlisle. I’m changing the catcode of # because I want macros like \estrofa# or \antifona# to indicate numbered stanzas and numbered antiphons. I’m preparing an interface for someone who has ->never used LaTeX<-, and I intend to make it as user-friendly as possible :).

@DavidCarlisle Regarding the first response, yesterday I implemented a solution that changes the paragraph settings, but the problem is that I want the stanzas, refrains, and so on not to break between page changes. Since I’m using \obeylines, each line of a stanza is a paragraph, and I don’t know how to add a \nobreak at the end of each line.
I’m adding a simple working example in the post. If it can be solved there, I can implement it in my project.

why not use \estrofa* rather than \estrofa# ? introducing a command that breaks all latex syntax rules and so will have lots of extra constraints such as will not  work inside a \parbox or tabularx or beamer frame,  will confuse anyone who looks at a latex tutorial to see what # means in latex.   \section \section*, \caption \caption*  etc is such a well established convention why break it?

@DavidCarlisle Because the # is much more descriptive in terms of numbering. My friend neither knows nor has ever used LaTeX. The conventions of "*" don’t affect him and don’t weigh on him (and no one else but him will use it). It will make much more sense for him to use and remember that \estrofa# is for numbered stanzas and \estrofa is for unnumbered stanzas. He is writing the songbook for his parish.

@DavidCarlisle He’s using LaTeX because he needed a thematic index, an alphabetical index at end, and a convenient way to load all the information without getting tangled up with styles. The whole interface is already built.
Here’s a sample for you: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i6ngclxh4zuffJt8OLGB3RAVypMU9t-f/view

If I understand well you want to minimize markup and to put some parts of text to \vboxes. Then you can open the a group at begin of environment and close it at the end. The \estrofa and \estribillo macros used inside the environment close the group (i.e. they close the \vbox if it is opened), allow page break and open \vbox again.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}

\newenvironment{canto}{\bgroup}{\egroup}

\def\estrofa{\egroup\medskip\vbox\bgroup {\bf Verse:}\obeylines}
\def\estribillo{\egroup\medskip\vbox\bgroup {\bf Chorus:}\obeylines}


\begin{document}

%Current interface

\begin{canto}
    \estrofa
    linea 1
    linea 2
    linea 3

    \estrofa
    linea 1
    linea 2
    linea 3

    \estribillo
    linea 1
    linea 2
    linea 3
\end{canto}

\end{document}

